# python math.log inaccurate output at larger int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, decimal, floating-accuracy

This is my code and i am trying to use math.log to find log of an int.
i tried most of the way to solve inaccurate log but nothing seems to work my piece of code :

```
num = 810333333333333333253432343224234
print(num)
getcontext().prec = 100 # set the precision  (no. of digits)
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN  # this will effectively truncate
logA = Decimal(math.log(num,2))

print(logA)
#find num using component of logs
seedfrac = Decimal(logA - int(logA))
nonfrac = 2**int(logA)
frac = Decimal(2**seedfrac)
print(Decimal(frac*nonfrac))
#find num directly 
print(Decimal(2**logA ))
```

Output to check values:

```
810333333333333333253432343224234
109.320214523928456173962331376969814300537109375
810333333333340688230991571062453.5576735355138989553226940926052307835750320132600744995177525695124
810333333333340688230991571062453.5576735355138989553226940926052307835750320132600744995177525695128
```

Please reply if you know any workaround,Thanks.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Just a guess, but at some point in the calculation there's probably floating point numbers, if you need it super accurate just stick with `Decimal` :P

Comment: Note that Python 3 has `math.log2`, which is a touch more accurate than using `math.log` with a base of `2.0`. BTW, what are you using this for? It's unusual that the precision of a Python `float` isn't enough for most real-world things; there may be better ways to do what you're looking for (like the `int.bit_length` method, for example, if what you want is the floor of the log base 2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.log` only works on floats, so when you do `Decimal(math.log(num,2))` you're just calling Decimal on the result of converting `num` to a float and then taking its float-precision log.

Convert your number to a Decimal instance first, preserving the precision, and then use one of its logarithm methods (newlines inserted below for readability):

```
In [22]: Decimal(num)
Out[22]: Decimal('810333333333333333253432343224234')

In [23]: Decimal(num).ln()
Out[23]: Decimal('75.77499847546938418941086142055648421904630259496362044
                  157156139031463040418047508186428539214239394')

In [24]: Decimal(num).ln().exp()
Out[24]: Decimal('810333333333333333253432343224234.0000000000000000000000
                  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020')

In [25]: Decimal(num).ln() / Decimal(2).ln()
Out[25]: Decimal('109.32021452392844307936383214097698765413874994582696830
                  23528366628242511675596034347551786781907708')

In [26]: 2**(Decimal(num).ln() / Decimal(2).ln())
Out[26]: Decimal('810333333333333333253432343224233.999999999999999999999
                  9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999548')
```

Comment: This is correct, of course, but `result of converting num to a float and then taking its float-precision log` is a bit misleading: In this case, that's exactly what happens, but in general `math.log()` doesn't *always* convert its argument to a float - it also works for integers which are too big to be converted to a float! (Ie. `float(2**1024)` raises `OverflowError`, but `math.log(2**1024)` still gives a result with no problems)